# Can I binding a function defined in another user-control as current event handler?

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding

I want to use a function defined in another user control as the event handler for this control. Is there any way I can fulfill it by using binding? Or the binding can only be used for attribute rather than event handler?

For example:

```
 <my:Search x:Name="queryControl" KeyDown=""/>
 <my:Measurement x:Name="measureTool" />
```

In the Measurement code behind:

```
 public partial class Measurement : UserControl {
    public void Measure2Tool(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
 }
```

Can I use binding to assign the Measure2Tool function as the event handler for the Search control's KeyDown event handler? How?

Thanks for your input!

Wei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events do not accept binding, so you can't do that directly. What you can do to achieve that is use behaviors like the `CallMethodAction` with and `EventTrigger` (the event you want to handle).

```
<my:Search x:Name="queryControl>
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
      <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=measureTool}" 
                           MethodName="{Binding Measure2Tool}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
<my:Search x:Name="queryControl>
```

with

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

Hope this helps :)